# How to solve "Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)" error in react app environment

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm using environment variables to avoid from hardcoding my API key into my config files.

Tried a lot of things: making sure I copied the API keys correctly, restarting my dev server, verifying identity using the firebase-admin npm module etc. etc.

**src/firebase.init.js**

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId,
};
```

**.env.local**

```
REACT_APP_apiKey=xxxx
REACT_APP_authDomain=xxx
REACT_APP_projectId=xxx
REACT_APP_storageBucket=xxx
REACT_APP_messagingSenderId=xxx
REACT_APP_appId=xxx
```

then in console show this error

`Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).`

How solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

ENV key attribute shoud be  all uppercase

x -> REACT_APP_apiKey=xxxx

✓ -> REACT_APP_APIKEY=xxxx

Answer (score -1):

Environment variables are case-sensitive. By convention, but not rule, environment variable names are always capitalized.

I had a same issue. Wrapping Env variables into template string solved my problem. Like:

```
apiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
```